# How to get 2 aggregate functions in one FetchXML script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, fetchxml

Let's say I have a dataset:

```
+--------+-------+----------+
| Animal | Price | FoodCost |
+--------+-------+----------+
|      1 |    23 |       22 |
|      1 |    32 |       33 |
|      1 |     7 |       69 |
|      2 |    45 |       55 |
|      2 |   432 |       82 |
|      2 |    33 |       34 |
|      3 |    67 |       44 |
|      5 |   671 |       62 |
|      8 |   234 |       43 |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

The result that I am looking for in my tablix is:

```
+--------+-------+----------+
| Animal | Price | FoodCost |
+--------+-------+----------+
|      1 |    62 |      124 |
|      2 |   510 |      171 |
|      3 |    67 |       44 |
|      5 |   671 |       62 |
|      8 |   234 |       43 |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

I understand how to do 1 aggregate, but how would I do 2 aggregates, **namely, summing the price and the foodcost for each animal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL:**

```
select Animal, sum(Price) as Sum_Price, sum(FoodCost)  as sum_foodcost
from dbo.AggegateTest
group by Animal
```

Generated **FetchXML:** with http://sql2fetchxml.com/

```
<fetch aggregate="true" mapping="logical">
  <entity name="AggegateTest">
    <attribute name="Animal" alias="AggegateTest1.Animal" />
    <attribute name="price" alias="Sum_Price" aggregate="sum" />
    <attribute name="foodcost" alias="sum_foodcost" aggregate="sum" />
    <attribute name="Animal" alias="Animal" groupby="true" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```